# Can I change the accepted format in NestJS for the @SubscribeMessage() decorator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, nestjs

Hi I am creating a basic websocket server in nestJS that has this code for subscribing to a message:

```
  @SubscribeMessage('init')
  handleEvent(
    @MessageBody() data: string,
    @ConnectedSocket() client: WebSocket,
  ) {
    console.log('message received!');
    console.log(data);
    return 'hello world!';
  }
```

This will only activate when the format of the message is `{event:'eventName', data:{someData}` since that is just the default format for `@SubscribeMessage()`.

My question is this: If I am not able to change the format of the message that the client sends, how can I change the default accepted format of `@SubscribeMessage()`? Would a custom adapter be the right choice? If so an example would really be helpful!